# Load pages into DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking for some code that will load a page inside of a DIV w/ JQuery.

Basically, when the page loads I would like to load

displaycatch.php into a DIV

```
<div id="results">Content for  id "results" Goes Here</div>
```

Then, I would like to create a button that loads a different page inside that DIV content.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the very simple ajax call from a button. On success, the response is put into your DIV

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "foo=bar&fooo=baz",
   success: function(msg){
     $("#results").html(msg);
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: I did get this code to work, but it broke some o my other jQuery code (show/hid DIV)

Comment: This is the code that no longer Toggles

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#loginhide').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#login').toggle('show');
    });
});

Comment: Change it with this. $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#loginhide').click(function() { 
  $('#login').toggle('show'); 
 });
 $("#button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: "foo=bar&fooo=baz",
      success: function(msg){
        $("#results").html(msg);
      }
   });
 });
});

Comment: Hmm.. Still doesn't seem to work.  That Toogle functions works, but now the page doesn't load in #results

Comment: Debug it with firebug. Look what's the response. May be your server side code has some error

Comment: Ok, I think I have it working now.  It was code on my target page breaking my jQuery functions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#results')
    .load('displaycatch.php')
    .after($('<button/>',{text:'Load another','type':'button'}).click(function(){
        $('#results').load('displayanother.php')
    }));
);
```

That will load displaycatch.php into #results when page is loaded, then insert button after it, which on click will load different page. Also, it was unclear, if you already have button or want to create it dynamically.

Comment: Hmm..  I'm having a hard time getting this code to work.  I'm using jquery-1.4.2.min.js.  I tried removing my existing button and just loading displaycatch.php into DIV 'results'.  Still nothing.

Comment: I did read through Pekka's link and I'm not even able to get the most simple example to load into #results

$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Is ajax folder in the same dir as page where you run load from?

Comment: No, not in the same directory.  It doesn't matter what URL I pass into load('');  I've even tried passing http://google.com into there and no difference.

Comment: Google shouldn't work because of same origin policy, only file from domain your page is on. If it's not in the same directory, relative path obviously would result with nothing, try absolute.